# Dexie: how to query by date?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, indexeddb, dexie

I'm trying to build a "logs" table (my goals its to know how much time the app is being used), so I created a function that detects if the user is inactive after a certain period of time.

The table is like this:

```
dblogs.version(1).stores({
    aLogs: "++id, story_id, user_id, session_start, session_end, words_written"
});
```

So when the user is active I create a new record on aLogs, example:

```
0, 1 , 19 , 2021/06/30 10:15:10
```

the user `19` started typing at `2021/06/30 10:15:10`(this goes in session_start) then if the user goes inactive I add the current datetime to session_end

Example:

```
  0, 1 , 19 , 2021/06/30 10:15:10, 2021/06/30 12:15:48
```

so basically the user estimated time is the difference between those 2 dates **(in this case its 2h 0m 38s)**

my goal is to have several of these logs, then run a loop on it and story the amount of seconds the user spent "today"

how do I query this on Dexie?

I have tried `await dblogs.aLogs.get({session_start : "2021/06/30"});` but it returns undefined

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have the following index:

[user_id+story_id+session_start]

This would allow efficient queries to retrieve all log entries for given user, story and day:

```
const result = await dblogs.aLogs
    .where('[user_id+story_id+session_start]')
    .between (
      [userId, storyId, dayStart],
      [userId, storyId, dayEnd])
    .toArray();

const totalSpentToday = results.reduce(
  (sum, {session_start, session_end}) =>
    sum + Math.min(dayEnd, session_end) - session_start);
```

If you need to catch sessions that overlaps between yesterday and current date, you could consider adjusting dayStart (in the between clause) to some reasonable amount of hours before dayStart and then from the result, ignore (subtract) durations that is not within current date.

Read more about compound indexes here: https://dexie.org/docs/Compound-Index